# Accessing another cluster from a Kubernetes pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm running jenkins in GKE. A step of the build is using `kubectl` to deploy another cluster. I have gcloud-sdk installed in the jenkins container. The step of the build in question does this:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /etc/secrets/google-service-account
gcloud config set project XXXX
gcloud config set account xxxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ANOTHER_CLUSTER
```

However I get this error (it works as expected locally though):

```
kubectl get pod
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Note: I noticed that with no config at all (~/.kube is empty) I'm able to use kubectl and get access to the cluster where the pod is currently running. 
I'm not sure how it does that, does it use /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ to access the cluster

EDIT: Not tested if it works yet, but adding a service account to the target cluster and using that in jenkins might work:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/ (search jenkins)

Comment: Did you try to figure out why `get-credentials` didn't generate any kubeconfig? A service account would work, but you'd still have to push the credentials to Jenkins' kubeconfig file manually.

Comment: It did, however it seems that in new version of kubernetes v1.3.5 you still have to do the whole OAUTH stuff. So it's a version issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here: [kubectl oauth2 authentication with container engine fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040278/kubectl-oauth2-authentication-with-container-engine-fails)

What you need to do before doing `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /etc/secrets/google-service-account` is to set gcloud to the old mode of auth:

```
CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE=True
gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
```

I have not succeded however using the other env var: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`